# Email SQL query results

Tags: sql-server-2008

I would like to send an email status of all the tables have been modified within a day. This is what I tried:

```
EXEC msdb.dbo.sp_send_dbmail 
   @profile_name='EmailProfile', 
   @recipients='myemail@email.com', 
   @subject='Import status', 
   @body= 'Data import precess completed.', 
   @query = 'SELECT OBJECT_NAME(OBJECT_ID) AS Tables, last_user_update AS Updated 
             FROM sys.dm_db_index_usage_stats 
            WHERE database_id = DB_ID(''DatabaseName'') 
               AND last_user_update >= DATEADD(DAY, 0, DATEDIFF(DAY, 0, CURRENT_TIMESTAMP))', 
   @attach_query_result_as_file = 1, @query_attachment_filename ='Results.txt'
```

Email came through with file Result.txt attached but under Tables column there are no tables' name instead just NULL. On Updated column has all date/time stamp  of the last modification of each table.
Do you know why table's names are not listed?

Comment: You should format your sql...

Comment: @AbeMiessler how do I format my SQL?

Comment: Well there is no official way, but whatever makes it more readable.  I went ahead and formatted your SQL to give you an idea...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

See [MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms186301%28v=sql.90%29.aspx).

> OBJECT_NAME 
>   Returns NULL on error or if a caller does not have permission to view the object.

Or maybe the NULLs are representing temporary tables.

The metadata function OBJECT_NAME is database specific and uses information from the catalog tables in the current database. If you run the query in a different database (say master) then the names will either be wrong (because object_id may match a different object in master database) or NULL. So in order to get the correct object name, the query has to be executed in the context of the database you are interested.

Comment: when I ran just the Select query then it returned all the table's names. What permission are we talking about here?